# UILabel Inside UITableViewCell Not Expanding to Show Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which contains two `UILabel`s. One is for **Title** and the other is for **Abstract**. The abstract is returned from web service and it is at least 10 lines long. I want to display all of those lines in the `UILabel`.

I have set the abstract `UILabel` **noOfLines** to 0. The linebreak is set as **wordwrapping**. I even invoke `sizeToFit` after assigning the abstract text as shown below:

```
-(void) configure:(Story *)story
{
    self.titleLabel.text = story.title;

    self.abstractLabel.text = story.abstract;

    [self.abstractLabel sizeToFit];
}
```

The `UITableView` `cellForRowIndex` is shown below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StoryCell";
    StoryCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Story *story = [_stories objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [cell configure:story];

    return cell;
}
```

The result is shown below:

[image]

Comment: The sizeToFit method will size the UILabels frame to fit it's superview which in this case is the UITableViewCell. Instead you need to estimate the size of the text using boundingRectWithSize: plus the size of the title to correctly size the UITableViewCell in heightForRowAtIndexPath: and then call sizeToFit on the UILabel. If you are using AutoLayout it's a different story, which I do not have experience with yet.

Comment: Yes, I am using Autolayout. Also there are no constraints on the UILabel so it should expand according to the text size when sizeToFit is called.

Comment: are you setting the row height? Are you setting the setting the frame height of your cell?

Comment: Turns out it was Autolayout constraints. I will post the answer in few hours.

Comment: John, I could actually use your answer if you can still post it, I'm having the same issue.

Comment: What was the solution? I have the same issue.